# Display Contents of s3 hosted text file using AWS SDK

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm using the Amazon AWS SDK to get the contents of a s3 hosted text file and echo it out.  So far I'm only able to get an array with headers and the content but can not echo the content itself...

```
$s3 = new AmazonS3();
$response = $s3->get_object('bucket', "mdtxt-$id");
var_dump($response);
```

^^Gives an array, however if I change line 3 to the following I get an error

CFResponse Object ( [header] => Array ( [x-amz-id-2] => l9+fT8HwfHPh5Y/y4h9VwU0k0sHexJ9nLbmVIW5HxosFoX+inc6yxKUrI8MjmYr+ [x-amz-request-id] => 1DB86A5E18A9675F [date] => Thu, 26 Jan 2012 22:30:59 GMT [last-modified] => Thu, 26 Jan 2012 20:23:03 GMT [etag] => "7987334c1e562dfe2e3e55a20de4928e" [accept-ranges] => bytes [content-type] => application/octet-stream [content-length] => 1865 [connection] => close [server] => AmazonS3 [_info] => Array ( [url] => https://wxdata.s3.amazonaws.com/mdtxt-20120076 [content_type] => application/octet-stream [http_code] => 200 [header_size] => 379 [request_size] => 685 [filetime] => 1327609383 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.038435 [namelookup_time] => 0.003164 [connect_time] => 0.004254 [pretransfer_time] => 0.014878 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 1865 [speed_download] => 48523 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => 1865 [upload_content_length] => 0 [starttransfer_time] => 0.038372 [redirect_time] => 0 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [method] => GET ) [x-aws-request-url] => https://wxdata.s3.amazonaws.com/mdtxt-20120076 [x-aws-redirects] => 0 [x-aws-stringtosign] => GET application/x-www-form-urlencoded Thu, 26 Jan 2012 22:30:57 GMT /wxdata/mdtxt-20120076 [x-aws-requestheaders] => Array ( [Expect] => 100-continue [Content-Type] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded [Date] => Thu, 26 Jan 2012 22:30:57 GMT [Authorization] => AWS 04XXSNW4PEJ4CMVKP782:iSCbNTrtJ69m3LFycdJmv21JI3E= ) ) [body] => MESOSCALE DISCUSSION 0076 NWS STORM PREDICTION CENTER NORMAN OK 0216 PM CST THU JAN 26 2012 AREAS AFFECTED...GA...NRN FL CONCERNING...SEVERE POTENTIAL...WATCH LIKELY VALID 262016Z - 262215Z ONE OR TWO ADDITIONAL WWS MAY BE NEEDED ACROSS PARTS OF THE EASTERN GULF STATES AND SOUTHERN APPALACHIANS REGION BETWEEN NOW AND 00-01Z. THE SQUALL LINE OVER THE NORTHEASTERN GULF OF MEXICO INTO THE WESTERN FLORIDA PANHANDLE HAS WEAKENED SOME. HOWEVER...IT APPEARS TO BE MAINTAINING SUFFICIENT STRENGTH TO CONTINUE SUPPORTING A RISK FOR DAMAGING WIND GUSTS/ISOLATED TORNADOES AS IT PROGRESSES EASTWARD ACROSS MUCH OF SOUTHWEST GEORGIA AND THE FLORIDA BIG BEND REGION BY 23-00Z. FARTHER NORTH...MORE UNCERTAINTY CONCERNING LONGER TERM CONVECTIVE TRENDS EXISTS. BUT THERE STILL APPEARS POTENTIAL FOR SIGNIFICANT INTENSIFICATION OF CONVECTION LATE THIS AFTERNOON AND EVENING. MORE RAPID DEEPENING OF A SURFACE LOW NOW LIFTING OUT OF THE NORTH CENTRAL GULF COAST STATES TOWARD CENTRAL/EASTERN KENTUCKY WILL LIKELY CONTRIBUTE TO FURTHER INTENSIFICATION OF SOUTHERLY 850 MB FLOW IN EXCESS OF 50-60 KTS...WHICH WILL ENLARGE LOW-LEVEL HODOGRAPHS ALONG AND AHEAD OF THE RESIDUAL EASTWARD ADVANCING CONVECTIVE BAND. THE INTERSECTION OF THIS CONVECTION WITH A REMNANT NEAR SURFACE BAROCLINIC ZONE TO THE LEE OF THE SOUTHERN APPALACHIANS COULD PROVIDE A FOCUS FOR ENHANCED SEVERE WEATHER POTENTIAL. THIS MAY INCLUDE SUPERCELLS WITH TORNADOES...NEAR/NORTH OF ATLANTA INTO WESTERN SOUTH CAROLINA...AS THE REMNANTS OF AN UPSTREAM LOW BEGIN LIFTING THROUGH THE TENNESSEE VALLEY BY 00-03Z. ..KERR.. 01/26/2012 ...PLEASE SEE WWW.SPC.NOAA.GOV FOR GRAPHIC PRODUCT... ATTN...WFO...CAE...GSP...FFC...TAE...BMX... LAT...LON 29028616 30478583 31358574 32868530 33948523 34308412 35038236 34948139 34518075 33278202 32148277 30128402 29318464 29028616 [status] => 200 )

```
var_dump($response["body"]);
```

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type CFResponse as array in /home/websites/md/view.php on line 38

Line 38 is the line I changed.  I need to stay away from things like s3fs

Comment: please format the post better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not give you an array — it gives you a `CFResponse` object.

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#i=CFResponse

`$response->body`, not `$response['body']`.